# How to translate Change in Duty Cycle?

Tags: sensor, pwm, duty-cycle

Morning! 
I have a sensor, output of which is change in Duty Cycle of current. Now, this sensor is to be used with a MCU. 
My knowledge of sensors with change in duty cycle as output is limited. So,i have the following question:

1. Would the change in Duty Cycle of current translate into change in duty cycle of Voltage if a resistor is attached at the output of the sensor?
2. Given such a case, what's the deciding factor for Sinking output vs Sourcing output?

In this case, its a Wheel Speed Sensor, output of which is change in duty cycle.

Thanks for you consideration!!

Comment: It might be worth adding a part number / datasheet for the sensor.

Comment: Its more of an analytical question, i dont have a part number or datasheet of the same!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Would the change in Duty Cycle of current translate into change in duty cycle of Voltage if a resistor is attached at the output of the sensor?

yes, of course

> Given such a case, what's the deciding factor for Sinking output vs Sourcing output?

If you have an output with a full driver (not for instance an open collector / sink only driver) you could attach the resistor to ground to get a voltage signal that is time-wise identical to your current signal (high when current is is sourced), or you could attach the resistor to Vcc to get the inverse (low when current is sunken). What to prefer is a matte of system design.

My guess is that you have an open-collector type sensor, in which case you will have to connect a resistor to Vcc, because the sensor can only sink current.

BTW, are you sure it is the duty cycle you are interested in? Wheel speed sensors are often of the magnet/hall-sensor or LED/fototodiode type, which produce pulses at a *frequency* proportional to the speed. The duty cycle may change too, but is in most cases not what you should be measuring.

Comment: +1, I was thinking the same on duty cycle. I guess as well as frequency pulse length would be useful for some encoders so I wondered if the OP was using the right terms.

Comment: Thanks a tonne mate! I know its an AMR sensor with current as output but beyond which i have no substantial data!